# Is it "telnet:" or the port 4161 that is telling me that I'm connecting to an UDP server?

Tags: telnet, udp

I am asking this question because I am not meeting UDP and telnet often...

To prepare myself for a development, I am reading a documentation where I will have to connect to a `telnet://x.y.z:4161` url.

I know, because one at work told me, that it's an UDP server that is behind,
but what if I didn't know that, would tell me this?

the `4161` port, that is dedicated for UDP exchanges, I think.
But could it be also the `telnet://` protocol mention that carries this information?

What does the `telnet:` protocol means here?
"*I don't know exactly the kind of network communication I have here*"?

Comment: I don't know. Is it? You make no mention of being told in the body of the question, and even suggest that you are not.

Comment: My English isn't good. I know that I will use an UDP server (reading the paper, and my teammates told me that). But the `telnet:` surprised me. I didn't understand why it was here. What was its meaning. Maybe I was expecting seeing things like `tcp://x.y.z` or `udp://x.y.z:4161` if they can exist, I don't know. But `telnet://x.y.z:4161` was new for me.

Comment: related but not duplicate (`telnet`, as a client is deprecated by `nc` (netcat)


: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696129/how-to-send-only-one-udp-packet-with-netcat

Answer (score 3):

Telnet is a protocol on top of TCP, so you will only get a connection if there is a TCP service listening on port 4161.
It does not matter whether there is also a service that receives UDP packets addressed to that port; that would be completely separate from the TCP service.

Some standard services (such as DNS, Port 53) have definitions for TCP and UDP, so clients can use either if the server provides them, but this is just a convention, there's no technical connection between those services.

Comment: nice answer! I must have missed it while I was typing mine. You've put it much clearer than I did: TCP ports have *nothing* to do with UDP ports. They just happen to use the same range of integers, but you can have a file server running on TCP port 1234 and a streaming server on UDP port 1234 and they won't conflict, because ports are concepts "internal" to TCP and UDP, and not something on the common layer(s) below (i.e., IP).

Answer (score 2):

> the 4161 port, that is dedicated for UDP exchanges, I think.

No such thing exists. Ports in UDP and TCP do not conflict, at all.

> I know, because one at work told me, that it's an UDP server that is behind,

why aren't you asking them then? It seems strange what they tell you, since telnet is **not** a UDP protocol.

> What does the telnet: protocol means here?

in a URI like `telnet://x.y.z.v:4161`, `telnet` is called the *scheme*, and these are officially registered; see the [IANA Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) of URI schemes:

| URI Scheme | Template | Description | Status | Well-Known URI Support | Reference | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| telnet |  | Reference to interactive sessions | Permanent | - | [[RFC4248](https://www.iana.org/go/rfc4248)] |  |

`telnet` is quite unambiguously registered for usage with [RFC4248](https://www.iana.org/go/rfc4248), and that very clearly refers to the [telnet protocol RFC854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854), and that very clearly says "TCP", not "UDP"; from the first paragraph of actual content:

> ## General Considerations
>
> A TELNET connection is a Transmission Control Protocol (TCP)
> connection used to transmit data with interspersed TELNET control
> information.

So, I really don't see where UDP could even theoretically have anything to do with a `telnet:` URL.

Answer (score 1):

A UDP port is not a TCP port, and telnet uses TCP. Therefore it will not connect to a UDP port.

Answer (score -1):

I have a problem with the phrase "behind a UDP server".  That's kind of like, "behind a vehicle with wheels" and thinking that it's important that it is a car vs. truck.

I don't know if it is intentional or not or if you are misunderstanding, but there's nothing special about "udp server" that saying something is behind it could have any real meaning.

In this context, "server" is anything that listens on a port.  It doesn't matter much if it is TCP or UDP.  What matters is what protocol it uses on top of TCP or UDP.  A telnet server is TCP only.   Some VPN protocols use TCP or UDP, and something could tunnel through a firewall using a VPN, and that might be considered "behind", but then you'd say behind a firewall or behind a vpn, not behind UDP.

You should go back to the person who said it was "behind a udp server" and get clarification and focus on what kind of server rather than "tcp" or "udp".